# Can web pages be served from both Apache and Flask separately?

Tags: apache, flask

I wanted to branch out from building standalone Python apps to central web pages that can be used for various tasks at work. I have access to a server running Apache. It has some pages built by someone who left the company and now I want to build on what he did. I've built an Apache server at home to practice on, and I've added Flask to it. I built a couple of simple html pages, put them in the templates directory, and I can get to them as expected and I even built a form with a python back end file.

What I didn't expect is that I can ONLY get to pages in the templates directory. I can't, say, get an html page in the normal "root" directory (/var/www/html). If I go to, say, 192.168.0.25, I get to my page in the templates directory. But if I try any other directory, even just 192.168.0.25/testpage.html, I get a 404 error.

The only thing I added to my base 000-default.conf was:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/app.wsgi
<Directory /var/www/html>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I'd like to be able to serve the existing pages in the server at work in Apache and mine from Flask. Is this possible, or am I going to have to figure a way to move everything to Flask if I decide to continue with that server?

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. apache2 2.4.52, and Flask 2.3.2.

I don't really know what to try. Web servers are not in my wheelhouse. I don't really even know what questions to ask to search for, so I was hoping someone here could give me some direction. I've seen some questions here that appear similar, but not close enough (to me) to my question.